# What does (NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * __nonnull) mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

The parameter type is (`NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * __nonnull`), and it means the parameter should be a dictionary and never be null. Then what does `<NSString *, id>` means? Are 'NSString *' and 'id' protocol names?
Does it mean that dictionary must be a json? But NSString are always object.
Anyone help?

Comment: We are talking about Objective-C here. You should really, really know what NSString* means and what id means. And when you download a new Xcode version, do yourself a favour and read the release notes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the syntax of **Objective C light weight generics**. This feature is mainly included for fixing Objective C - Swift interoperability issues.

`NSDictionary<NSString *,id>` means, the dictionary keys should be of type `NSString` and it's value can be any type of object (`id`).

**For Example:**
If you want to declare a dictionary that will hold NSString values only, you can declare it like:

```
NSDictionary<NSString *,NSString *> *stringDictionary;
```

However in Objective C, you can set any-type of values to this dictionary, there will be no errors. But if you are using the same `stringDictionary` object from a swift class, you can only set a string value to this dictionary, otherwise it'll throw an error.

Please check this [article](http://drekka.ghost.io/objective-c-generics/) for more details.

Comment: point of confusion is that `NSDictionary` has **two** inputs, so if we want to make its objects to conform into being a specific type then we must write **two** objects inside the angle brackets `<>` one for *key* and one for *value*